# Add active after click link

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have this code below, and I wanted to know how I can make it active after the click?

```css
.sprite {
  background: url(https://liveplanet.app.br/assets/images/sprite-icons.png) no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.audio {
  background-position: 0px -720px;
}

a.audio:hover {
  background-position: -40px -720px;
}

a.audio:active {
  background-position: -80px -720px;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a (click)="toggleAudio()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="sprite audio" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Audio"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it active after the click"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your post into an executable snippet. I didn't alter any of the script, please review if it is executing as intended

Comment: I suspect you'd like to visually indicate which link has been clicked, marking it "currently active", correct? It can be done several different ways but we'd need a broader context of the code markup and how things work.

Comment: The link uses an image sprite and this link would be audio, but when clicked it would have the background with a fixed image different from when not clicked

Comment: Your markup indicates that you're using a framework like Angular. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I'm using.

Comment: So tag it and mention it in your question. It's crucial to proper answers.

Answer (score 0):

As [per the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-active), the `:active` CSS selector will only match

> while an element is being activated by the user

What you're looking for is the `:focus` pseudo selector, which also matches after your click (without any additional JavaScript).

```
a.audio:focus { ... }
```

If you want to control the active element (`document.activeElement`) with JavaScript, you can use the `focus()`. The CSS selector `:active` will not match.

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <!-- adapt click handler to current JavaScript framework -->
  <a (click)="toggleAudio(); this.focus();" href="javascript:void(0);" class="sprite audio" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Audio"></a>
</li>
```

An alternative approach to display that a link has been clicked, is to toggle a CSS separate class, with `element.classList.toggle()`.

```
<style>
  a.active { ... }
</style>

<li class="list-group-item">
  <!-- adapt click handler to current JavaScript framework -->
  <a (click)="toggleAudio(); this.classList.toggle('active');" href="javascript:void(0);" class="sprite audio" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Audio"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: But it should stay focus until you click it again

Comment: It does stay focused, and hence `:focus` will match. `:focus` will match until you activate any other element (e.g. click). That's the difference from `:active`.

Comment: What I wanted is for it to stay active until I clicked on it again.

Comment: What you're asking for isn't possible with CSS. If you `focus()` the element with JavaScript, the same element will be `document.activeElement`. The CSS selector `:active` will not match. You'll have to rethink, e.g. add an extra CSS class to the element on click.

Comment: How would this function in js?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a suggestion to toggle CSS class with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand you correctly, then you want this button (a button for controlling the audio) to have a active class when clicked on correct?  If so here is my proposal. Hopefully this can provide what you are looking to achieve. Let me know if this works for you or not.

You can see that when clicking on the button, if you look at it through inspect element. It will append a 'active' class on click, & remove it when clicked again.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/no-named-user/pen/abELyar

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#active');

a.onclick = function() {
  a.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.sprite {
  background: url(https://liveplanet.app.br/assets/images/sprite-icons.png) no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.audio {
  background-position: 0px -720px;
}

a.audio:hover {
  background-position: -40px -720px;
}

a.audio:active {
  background-position: -80px -720px;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-group-item">
  <a (click)="toggleAudio()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="sprite audio" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Audio" id = "active"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your code didn't work. It was not active in the muted audio image.

Comment: Hey Fabio, What exactly do you mean it did not work?   As I had mentioned when clicking on the button, you will see that it appends the 'active' class to the button when clicked. (You need to observe this function through inspect element, while clicking on the button) to see that it does indeed set a active class when clicked.         Unless I am still misunderstanding you're question & what you ultimately want to achieve, this approach is working as it should.